# Facebook login dialog doesn't open when using javascript

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Eclipse IDE on Mac. I've created a simple web page where if you click a button it will ask you to sign in to facebook. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
function getUserData(response) {
    if(response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            $('#loginBtn').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + response.name;
        });
    }
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxx',
            cookie     : true,  
            xfbml      : true,  
            version    : 'v2.8' 
          });

          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            getUserData(response);
          });
    };
          (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


//add event listener to login button
$('#loginBtn').on('click', function() {
    FB.login(getUserData, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
});
</script>

<button id="loginBtn">Hello</button>
<div id="response">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here i'm running this on local host. The url is http://localhost:8080/TestTest/index.jsp .. But when i run this application, I get this message on console. 
    **Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's 
    domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains 
    of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.**

How to change my domain URL?? How to include the domain of this URL to my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you need to add the url  http://localhost:8080 
To your facebook app ie at developers.facebook.com where you created your app in the first place.